# Magento/Argento Theme - Move Categories above Compare Products

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, navigation, sidebar

I have the Argento theme and I am trying to move the "Navigation" (categories list) above the "Compare Products" block in the left sidebar / left nav.  I am currently using the mall theme and have tried to modify the code in the following locations:

> app/design/frontend/argento/mall/layout/local.xml
>   app/design/frontend/argento/default/layout/argento.xml
>   app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml
>   app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tm/navigationpro/sidebar.phtml

None of these contain blocks which can be reordered or contain "before" or "after" tags in blocks or references.

Does anyone have experience with modifying the order of elements with the Argento Mall theme?  Can you direct me to the right file?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found it.  If anyone else is having similar issues, I went to this file:

> app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/tm/navigationpro.xml

And replaced this line:

```
<block type="navigationpro/navigation" name="navigationpro.left" template="tm/navigationpro/sidebar.phtml" before"-">
```

To this:

```
<block type="navigationpro/navigation" name="navigationpro.left" template="tm/navigationpro/sidebar.phtml" before"catalog.compare.sidebar">
```

This moves the categories above the compare block!